# selected two stage, consider for the date filtering by latest stage's date for power bi report

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

Suppose we have a slicer (stages) and user will select two stages and another slicer (completion date) for all work (jobs)

current logic :

I selected "second stage" and "third stage" for STAGES slicer
I selected 12/1/2022 to 1/1/2023 in the completion date slicer

I will see only "third stage" because "second stage"s "completion date" is not between the "completion date" range
(SEE CIRCLE IN RED)

What business wants :
They want to see both selected stages, and create a logic : look at the latest selected stage, if that latest selected stage's completion date within the slicer date range? bring the other selected stage regardless it's completion date

so I can calculate the variance days between these two
(SEE CIRCLE IN GREEN)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Ja1.png)

I'm currently working on a logic to use in sql script or dax in power bi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is a month old. You may have already solved it, but it intrigued me, and I would like to help you and anyone who may face a similar logic problem; first, I will tell you how I processed your case, then I will supply you with the TSQL script {Microsoft's SQL server 2019} that will return a table with the desired variance in a column.

> **My process was as follows:**

> > You said: the business wants to see both selected stages and create a logic that looks at the latest selected Stage if that stage completion date is within the slicer date range. Bring the other Stage chosen regardless of its completion date.

So, I analyzed the excel data that you provided and:

1. Realized that the data could describe different Jobs #1, #2, and ext., and each Job can have different stages; for example, Job #1 has six stages, and Job #2 may have four.
2. In general, forcing users to select only two Stages is not straightforward, so I thought of a solution that allows users to choose multiple Stages.
3. The trick is retrieving the other chosen Stages regardless of their completion date if that selected Stage's completion date is within the slicer date range. Because when you apply a filter using a where statement in SQL, it will return the rows in which the conditions are true, so a straightforward SQL won't do the trick but thank God for STRING_SPLIT relational operator, UNION Operator, EXISTS condition, LAG function, and subqueries :), which you can read about in the below links:

   https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/union.php

   https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/exists.php

   https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/lag.php

   https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16
4. The data needs an index to find the proper order of stages for each Job to find the variance between each consecutive Stage in each Job.

   a. We cannot index your data using Stages because it is a string value, even if it describes the numeric order of a job stage.

   b. We will use the completion date considering that the Second Stage starts after the First Stage.

> **The code (Documented to be more understandable) is:**

```
DECLARE @JobsID   varchar(500), -- If this variable is not assigned a value, then return all jobs that pass the supplied conditions according to the required Logic.
        @DateFrom DATE = CAST('2022-12-01' AS DATE), 
        @DateTo   DATE = CAST('2023-01-01' AS DATE),  
        @SelectedStage varchar(4000)  = 'SecondStage , ThirdStage,SixthStage'  -- Here, you need to supply the user with all Stages options available in your dataset so that he can assign values for this variable 
        ;   

DECLARE @JobsStages TABLE  -- Created a table variable to save and use/reuse the test data in the code
(
 STAGES  VARCHAR(100) ,
 JOBS    VARCHAR(50) ,
 [completion date] DATE
)
; 

WITH JobsStages AS -- Test Data
(
    SELECT 'FirstStage'  STAGES, '#0' JOBS ,    CAST('2021-01-22' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'SecondStage' STAGES, '#0' JOBS ,    CAST('2021-11-04' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'ThirdStage'  STAGES, '#0' JOBS ,    CAST('2021-12-15' AS DATE) [completion date] 
    UNION
    SELECT 'FirstStage'  STAGES, '#1' JOBS ,    CAST('2022-01-10' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'SecondStage' STAGES, '#1' JOBS ,    CAST('2022-11-02' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'ThirdStage'  STAGES, '#1' JOBS ,    CAST('2022-12-03' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'FourthStage' STAGES, '#1' JOBS ,    CAST('2023-01-04' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'FifthStage'  STAGES, '#1' JOBS ,    CAST('2023-02-05' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'SixthStage'  STAGES, '#1' JOBS ,    CAST('2023-03-06' AS DATE) [completion date] 
    UNION
    SELECT 'FirstStage'  STAGES, '#2' JOBS ,    CAST('2022-01-22' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'SecondStage' STAGES, '#2' JOBS ,    CAST('2022-11-04' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'ThirdStage'  STAGES, '#2' JOBS ,    CAST('2022-12-15' AS DATE) [completion date] UNION
    SELECT 'FourthStage' STAGES, '#2' JOBS ,    CAST('2023-01-14' AS DATE) [completion date]
)
INSERT INTO @JobsStages
SELECT * 
FROM JobsStages;

/*
    When you read this query, start by understanding the Subquery called Filtered_JobsStages logic, then
    how the main SELECT calculates the VarianceInDays column values.
*/

SELECT [JOBS],[STAGES],[completion date],
       LAG ([completion date]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [JOBS] ORDER BY [completion date] )  PreviousStageCompletionDate,
       DATEDIFF(Day , LAG ([completion date]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [JOBS] ORDER BY [completion date] ) , [completion date]) VarianceInDays    
FROM
    (
        /*
         1- The first result set for the UNION Operator will return the rows for the selected stages in the 
            given date range.

         2- The second result set for the UNION Operator will return the rows for the chosen Stages regardless 
            of their completion date if that selected Stage's completion date is within the slicer date range 
            for the same job for the first result set for the UNION Operator.
        */
        SELECT * 
        FROM @JobsStages JS1
        WHERE (
               [completion date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
               AND 
               [STAGES] IN (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SelectedStage, ','))
              )
              AND
              (
               JOBS = @JobsID
               OR
               @JobsID IS NULL -- So if the @JobsID is not assigned to a value, this parenthesis condition will return true.
              )
        UNION 
        SELECT * 
        FROM @JobsStages JS2
        WHERE 
             [STAGES] IN (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SelectedStage, ',')) 
             AND     
             EXISTS (   
                        SELECT 1 
                        FROM @JobsStages SQ
                        WHERE 
                             (
                               (
                                [completion date] BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
                                AND 
                                [STAGES] IN (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SelectedStage, ','))
                               )
                               AND
                               (
                                JOBS = @JobsID
                                OR
                                @JobsID IS NULL -- So if the @JobsID is not assigned to a value, this parenthesis condition will return true.
                               )
                             )
                             AND
                             SQ.JOBS = JS2.JOBS
                    )
    ) Filtered_JobsStages
ORDER by JOBS,[completion date];
```

*I hope I helped in a way; if so, please mark this as an answer and vote for it :)*

Comment: Hey @aseel
Sorry for delay
I saw your comment I couldn't have a time to read it before. I had a solution on power bi side (DAX) We were looking for a solution in the report side, but I had to say you have a great sample here.  I have seen your results in SSMS
To clarify what I have done earlier, one user can select two stages and the latest stage's datetime falls between date selection and the earliest stage's datetime doesn't matter if it falls between the date selection of before. Even if the date selection filters the page, I could bring the results to the report. Found it by accident:)